# Wireshark mean jitter rtp analysis

Tags: voip, wireshark, rtp

I would like to know how does wireshark calculate the mean jitter? Should it not be just the sum of all the jitters over the number of recieved packets? I have a stream (with packet loss) and when I run wireshark analysis for RTP then export analysis for this stream, sum all the jitter values and divide by the number of recieved packets, I get a smaller mean jitter than that of wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the file that implements the rtp analysis for wireshark mentioned in this link ([https://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP_statistics](http://here)). The file is called  **tap-rtp-common.c** and can be found here https://github.com/giuliano108/wireshark-rtpmon/blob/master/tap-rtp-common.c and It turns out that the mean jitter is not the sum of all the jitters but rather the sum of all the diffs (between timestamps and arrival times) over the total number of frames.